# Internationalisation works in local, not in remote

Tags: php, internationalization, smarty, gettext

I have some intriguing problem, I use gettext for internationalization purpose. When the user chooses some language, suppose 'en' (for english), I use some this :

```
    putenv("LC_ALL=en_US");
    @setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');

    $_SESSION['language'] = 'en_US.UTF8';
    $this->mySmarty->clearAllCache();//to clear the html parts that are stored in cache
```

The weird thing is that this works perfectly well in my localhost, but it fails when I push it on the remote server. By failing, I mean no translation is processed when changing language Someone could help ?

Answer (score 0):

You've missed the quotes around `en_US`:

```
@setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US');
```

Besides that, you may have to check whether the locale that you want to use is available on the hosted environment (`locale -a`). You can pass `setlocale` multiple arguments with different locale names in order of priority:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US', 'en_US.utf8', 'en', 'english');
```

To check if the locale is properly set use `var_dump` against the [expected value](http://php.net/setlocale).

Comment: Sure I edited my post, for sure I missed the quotes when writing the post. And the locale that I want to use indeed exists

Comment: Is `gettext` enabled on the server?

Comment: I think it is, how could I check it ? Btw, I var_dumped the locale that I use and it seems to be correct...

Comment: I ran 'which gettext', and I got /usr/bin/gettext

Comment: The php extension I mean, use `phpinfo()` or `php -m` to find out.